# lua code working, but stops before code is finished

Tags: lua

I am doing user input code for lua, and if you made an error typing the information, you can fix it by saying the thing you want to fix. After you type the two letters (for example say you spelt england wrong and spelt it englaund, you would type HT to fix it.) it prompts you to fix it, and after you do it it just says the code is finished even though it is not.

I have tried making the variables local, making the blocks all ifs and not elseifs.

```lua
--user input--
print('Hello, what is your name? ')
local name = io.read()
print('What is your last name?')
local LastName = io.read()
print('The place you live?')
local Hometown = io.read()
print('Lastly, what is your favourite video game?')
local VideoGame = io.read()

--Printing the information--
print(
  'You are ' .. name .. ' ' .. LastName ..
  ' you live in ' .. Hometown ..
  ' and your favourite video game is ' .. VideoGame .. '.'
)
print('right?')

-- confirmation --    
io.write("press 1 i was correct, and press 2 if i was wrong.")
answer = io.read()

if answer == "1" then
  print('Yay, I was correct!')

elseif answer == "2" then
  print('aww, I was wrong. Do you want to enter the information again?  Say yes or no.')

  local answer2 = io.read()

  if answer2 == "yes" then
    print('What would you like to change? Type either FN, LN, HT or VG to change which one you would like.')

    local answer3 = io.read()

    if answer3 == FN then
      io.write('Ok, please enter the corrected version of your first name.')
      answerFN = io.read()
      io.write('Here is the corrected version.')
      io.write(
        'You are ' .. answerFN .. ' ' .. LastName ..
        ' you live in ' .. Hometown ..
        ' and your favourite video game is ' .. answerVG .. '.'
      )
    end

    if answer3 == LN then
      print('Ok, please enter the corrected version of your last name.')
      answerLN = io.read()
      print('Here is the corrected version.')
      print(
        'You are ' .. name .. ' ' .. answerLN ..
        ' you live in ' .. Hometown ..
        ' and your favourite video game is ' .. answerVG .. '.'
      )
    end

    if answer3 == HT then
      print('Ok, please enter the corrected version of your hometown.')
      answerHT = io.read()
      print('Here is the corrected version.')
      print(
        'You are ' .. name .. ' ' .. LastName ..
        ' you live in ' .. answerHT ..
        ' and your favourite video game is ' .. answerVG .. '.'
      )
    end


    if answer3 == VG then
      print('Ok, please enter the corrected version of your favourite video game.')
      answerVG = io.read()
      print('Here is the corrected version.')
      print(
        'You are ' .. name .. ' ' .. LastName ..
        ' you live in ' .. Hometown ..
        ' and your favourite video game is ' .. answerVG .. '.'
      )
    end

    if answer2 == "no" then
      print('Alright, tough luck. You can run the code again if you change your mind.')
    end
  end
end
```

I expected it to print 'ok, put the corrected version of ...', but it didn't even work.

Comment: Firstly there is an `end` too much,  better use `elseif` for `answer2 == 'no'`. In this case you would never join the clause. Secondly the variables you are proofing `answer3` for don't exist. Maybe you forgot the string quotes, for instance `answer3 == 'FN'`. Additionally you forgot the local var definition for `answerFN`, `answerLN`, ... So make sure to define them if you didn't already before.
At least i would recommend you to write an function to print this standard string output (`You are bla bla you live in ...'`).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change `answer3 == VG` to `answer3 == "VG"` (and the others as well). Currently, it is comparing with a variable by the name `VG`, which presumably doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using variables instead of strings for reinputting info but the variables aren't set to anything. You are also using seperate if statements for each condition of reinputting info which can slow your program down loads.

Instead you may want to put

```
if answer3 == "FN" then
   ...
elseif answer3 == "LN" then
   ...
elseif answer3 == "HT" then
   ...
elseif answer3 == "VG" then
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

After you prompt the user to enter "yes" or "no" with the `'aww, I was wrong. Do you want to enter the information again?  Say yes or no.'` message, you ask what change is needed and store the user input in `answer3` variable.

But you are comparing the value of `answer3` to other *variables* like `FN`, `LN`, etc instead of strings like `"FN"` and `"LN"`.

Lua doesn't complain about this as undefined variables are considered to have `nil` value.

---

Also, you have used undefined variable `answerVG` when only `FN` or `LN` or `HT` is changed. Use the `VideoGame` variable instead.

---

When comparing the value of `answer3`, instead of using distinct `if .. end`s, you could use an if-else ladder like

```
if <condition1> then
    ...
elseif <condition2> then
    ...
else
    ...
end
```